# Insurance taken out when payed 3 times in a month

Tags: health-insurance, payroll

I worked at a company where I got payed every 2 weeks. Insurance would be taken out out of each check. On the months we got 3 checks they would still deduct insurance out of the 3rd check. Is that right? Every other company I worked for would not deduct from the 3rd check.

Comment: Ask HR. This is a company policy issue and in their bailiwick.

Answer (score 7):

> I worked at a company where I got payed every 2 weeks. Insurance would
> be taken out out of each check. On the months we got 3 checks they
> would still deduct insurance out of the 3rd check. Is that right?

It depends on how they calculated the premium.

If they said it is $300 a month, and then withheld $150 from each paycheck, then I would expect two paychecks a year would not have the premiums deducted.

If they said it was $300 per month and then withheld $138.46 from each check, then all 26 paychecks would look the same.

Over the years I have experienced both of these methods. It all works out in the end.

But if they said $300 a month, kept the $150 from each check, and then failed to adjust for that extra paycheck, ask HR for clarification.

> Every other company I worked for would not deduct from the 3rd check

I have had companies make the middle check the one without an insurance premium deducted.